# Font-awesome icon within button not activating onClick in React app

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am happy I can use font-awesome in my projects. I want to put some bars as my open/close button for my menu. The icon itself is not clickable, but the small area between the icon and the border still activates the onClick. The console.log I put in my event handler shows that the icon does not pass the 'name' property needed to activate the state change. Does anyone know how to get around this?

I have tried wrapping it in span and i elements. The icon does show up, but is just not activating the onClick, probably because it is not passing the 'name' property.

My event handler:

```
menuClick(event) {
  /*event.preventDefault();*/
  const name = event.target.name;
  console.log(name);
  this.setState({[name]:!this.state[name]})
}
```

My button:

```
<button 
    name="menuOpen" 
    style={props.data.menuOpen ? 
    buttonStyle : 
    null} 
    onClick={props.menuClick} 
    className="menuOpenButton">
        <FontAwesomeIcon name="menuOpen" icon="bars" size="3x" />
</button>
```

and the props are being passed to the child like this:

```
<Header 
    data={this.state}
    menuClick={this.menuClick} />
```

Comment: I guess it should be `onClick={this.menuClick}`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it is a child element, hence the props.menuClick. I added an onClick={props.menuClick} to the fontawesome, but still nothing.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code on how you're passing props. That might help.

Comment: Sure thing. Edited.

Comment: If you're passing through props then it should be `onClick={this.props.menuClick}`. As props is under this, not global for the component.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the event handler to listen for currentTarget instead of target.


const name = event.currentTarget.name;

Answer (score 0):

Changing the event handler to look for the currentTarget fixed it.

```
const name = event.currentTarget.name
```